# Equivalence relations, modular arithmetic, equivalence classes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is my issue. I can do modular arithmetic. I wrote a short essay on the topic. My problem comes when trying to understand equivalence classes.

So in the set of positive integers, and using mod 17. Then the equivalence class of the set of positive integers mod 17, are the integers that are divisible by 17.

Is the above statement correct? thank you for your time.

Comment: Not quite. There are $17$ equivalence classes.  **One** of them is the set of integers divisible by $17$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why are there $17$ equivalence classes?

Comment: Two numbers are equivalent (belong to the same family) modulo $17$ if their difference is divisible by $17$. An equivalence class is a family. One family consists of all the numbers that leave remainder $0$ on division by $17$. Another family is all the numbers that leave remainder $1$. And so on up to remainder $16$, a total of $17$ families in all.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how do partitions play in this? would mod 99, have 99 equivalence classe?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Each family has exactly one representative among $0$ to $98$.  Many of our calculations are done with that representative, though for example $98$ and $-1$ are in the same family (equivalence class) and working with $-1$ may be more convenient that working with $98$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas hey i wanted to thank you. I read an article that showed the material a little different. Then everything clicked! the $17$ equivalence classes makes so much more sense now! its like the commercial when the people barter and the minds explode with purple confetti. lololol thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. I did not write a formal answer because I thought some "back and forth" in comments might be more useful.